# Data flow issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dataflow

Getting error when trying to run Sql Command in SSIS package.

- Task: DataFlow Task
- Connection: ADO.NET
- Data Access mode: Sql Command
- Sql text:

  select from table where field1 = ? and field2 = ?

> Error:" No value given for one or more required parameters"

**More Information:**

*Execute Sql task in package:*

(General tab)
- Connection: ADO.NET
- SQL Statement:  `exec storedprocedureX ?,?`

(Parameter Mapping tab)

```
User::field1 , Input , String , 0 , -1
User::field2, Input, String, 1, -1
```

Variables set in package

- `field1` value `12C`
- `field2` value `15A`

What am I missing that is causing the variable values to not be read at Data flow level?  I have no problem at the Execute SQL task level.

Comment: SqlClient uses names rather than `?` as parameter markers. Change the query to something like `select from table where field1 = @field1 and field2 = @field2;` and define the parameters with those names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OLE DB Command in the data flow is different compared to the Execute SQL Task in the control flow.  You seem to be describing the Execute SQL Task correctly.

To use a variable in the data flow, you need to add it to the data flow -- the easiest way is to use a Derived Column with an expression.  Add a Derived Column to your Data Flow before the OLE DB Command and configure it as follows: Derived Column Name: field1; Derived Column: add as new column; Expression: @[User::field1].  Then in the OLE DB Command, under Column Mappings map the columns as Input Column: field1; Destination Column: Param_0, etc.

Comment: +1 Well said. I would add that the OP should be extremely careful with DB Commands as they are extremely slow. This is due to the fact that they fire off a single command to the DB for every row passing through. So, if performing UPDATES or DELETES on millions of rows, then the job may take several minutes to hours to complete. So, make sure that the command is only executing on a row that needs to change. Otherwise, bypass the row.